# How to encode decimal lines to hex?

Tags: python-3.x, hex, decimal

When i try this

```
f = open('j:/out.txt', 'r')
lines = []
for line in f:
    lines.append(line)
    f1 = open('j:/out1.txt', 'a')
    print (''.join(hex(int(c)) for c in line.strip('\n')))
    f1.write(''.join(hex(int(c)) for c in line.strip('\n')) + "\n")
    f1.close()
    print (line.strip('\n'))
```

it's encode return  some decimals strings not heximal , how make it correct for it return heximal value from dec ?

input data is only decimal lines.

answer

```
f = open('j:/out.txt', 'r')
lines = []
for line in f:
    lines.append(line)
    f1 = open('j:/out1.txt', 'a')
    for c in line.strip('\n').split():
        dec = c
        decimal = int(dec);
        inHexadecimal = hex(decimal);
        print (inHexadecimal.strip('0x'));
        f1 = open('j:/out1.txt', 'a')
        f1.write(inHexadecimal.strip('0x') + "\n")
        f1.close()
    print (line.strip('\n'))
```

Comment: I don't think that `for line in f` can do what you want it to do when `f` is a file descriptor.

Comment: if i use as input data ascii text , it reaturn hex value , maybe quation was incoret , and most been be how say what type of data return to hex - to this function.